# Moving a file in java

Tags: java, optimization

I am currently moving a file in java in the following way:

```
private static void moveFile(String fileName, String folderName) {
    String name= fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('\\'), fileName.length());
    new File(fileName).renameTo(new File(folderName+ File.separator + name));
}
```

Is there any faster way of doing this?  I need to optimize this code.

Comment: Using Java NIO: [Files.move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) is always an option

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html

Answer (score 2):

try with this

```
         Path source = ...
         Path newdir = ...
         Files.move(source, newdir.resolve(source.getFileName()), REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, if you are using Java 8 you should take a look at `Files.move(Path, Path, CopyOption...)`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-

Here's a simple example:

```
private static void moveFile(String fileName, String folderName) {
  Path src = Paths.get(fileName); // fileName is the absolute path.
  Path dest = Paths.get(folderName); // folderName is the absolute path.
  Files.move(src, dest); 
// Or if you want to replace an existing file with the same name:
// Files.move(src, dest, CopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any **faster** way of doing this? I need to optimize this code.

No, there isn't.

`Files.renameTo` is a better API<sup>1</sup>, but it isn't faster.

The performance bottleneck in renaming files is the performance of file system itself.  There is no scope for optimizing / improving performance in Java ... unless you can avoid the need to rename the file in the first place.

---

<sup>1 - If the operation fails, then you will get an exception that attempts to explain the failure.  By contrast, with `File.rename` you just get a `boolean` result; i.e. no explanation of what went wrong.</sup>